# Casting pointer type

Tags: c++, opencv

I see a piece of OpenCV code:

```
float *huedata = (float *)hue.data;
```

where `hue` is created by `Mat hue(Size(640,480),CV_32FC1)`

The `hue.data` returns a pointer `uchar*`, but I don't see why put `(float *)` instead of `(float)` in front of hue.data and also why need to cast to `float` rather keep using `uchar`?. Anyone can help explain this?

Comment: _"but I don't see why put (float *) instead of (float) in front of hue.data."_ Because pointers are pointers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to a float is a **completely different type of value** to a float itself.  This can be hard to grasp if you aren't used to pointers, so let me explain.

hue.data (as a pointer) holds a number which is an index to a location in memory.  Let's say, for instance, that hue.data holds the number **187**.  That means that it represents the **187th byte of memory**.  Now, lets say that the value stored at that memory location is the value **3.14**.  What you *actually care about* that value **3.14**.

Here is what you suggested:

```
float huedata = (float)hue.data;
```

After this line, you will have a variable huedata which stores the number **187**, since that is what was copied from hue.data.  The value **3.14** is completely ignored.

Here is what was originally written:

```
float *huedata = (float *)hue.data;
```

After this line, you will have a variable huedata which stores the number **187**, but is a pointer, which means it points to the memory location where you can find the value **3.14**.  Thus you still have access to the value **3.14**, which is what you really care about.

As for casting from (uchar*) to (float*).  Since pointers are just numbers representing memory locations, casting from one pointer type to a different one just means considering the value at that memory address a float instead of a uchar.  This is probably done because hue.data can represent different kinds of values in different circumstances, so they typed it as uchar, expecting the user to retype based on the circumstance.